# MockMvc error when validating ResultMatcher for swagger 2 on spring boot 2.1.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, mockmvc

I have an integration test that no longer works after updating to spring boot 2.1.0. In this test I perform the following:

```
 final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set("api_key", "apiKey");

        mockMvc.perform(post("/apiurl")
                                .headers(httpHeaders)
                                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(someObject)))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(swagger().isValid(getSwaggerUrl()));
```

the method `getsSwaggerUrl()` simply returns a string with the URL to the swagger api-docs. The exception is thrown in the line: `.andExpect(swagger().isValid(getSwaggerUrl()));`

When I run this test, the final expect throws this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call getReader() after getInputStream() has already been called for the current request

    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest.getReader(MockHttpServletRequest.java:716)
    at com.atlassian.oai.validator.mockmvc.MockMvcRequest.getReader(MockMvcRequest.java:118)
    at com.atlassian.oai.validator.mockmvc.MockMvcRequest.getBody(MockMvcRequest.java:99)
    at com.atlassian.oai.validator.mockmvc.MockMvcRequest.of(MockMvcRequest.java:91)
    at com.atlassian.oai.validator.mockmvc.SwaggerMatchers.lambda$isValid$0(SwaggerMatchers.java:45)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:195)
    at com.etpa.trader.api.swagger.OrderAPIIT.testPostOrder(APIIT.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I've been trying to find the underlying issue for hours but I cannot manage to do so. Googling this exception specifically for MockMvc or Swagger 2 or for their combination does not yield too many results.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Have you managed to find a solution to this?

Comment: From what I can tell this is only happening to me when validating POST methods. GET's seem to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There was a breaking change introduced in Spring Boot 2.1 (Spring 5.1.0.RELEASE). See [this PR](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/pull-requests/121/issue-181/diff) for details.

The `swagger-request-validator-mockmvc` lib has been updated to support Spring 5.1+. The fix is available in swagger-request-validator v2.2.0.

Note: If you are using Spring Boot < 2.1 (or Spring < 5.1) you will need to change you dependency to `swagger-request-validator-mockmvc-legacy` when moving to v2.2.0+.